# How to make action of other application?

Tags: cocoa

Greetings,
I need to make action in other (not mine) application. Lets say, Photoshop toolbar. Is there any way to click any button of Photoshop's toolbar from my cocoa application?

...

I found: 
- NSRunningApplication 
- Accessibility API 
- Quartz Events 
- [...and this](http://cocoadev.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=345)

But it's still not enought. Any idea? Any solution?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility or the ways described in that forum thread are the only two ways to manipulate an application that doesn't invite other applications to manipulate it.

Comment: Right, but..question is, if there is way to do that. :)